# Get HTML from query url (index.php?[arguments] ) Swift 3 ios

Tags: html, ios, swift, parsing, hpple

I'm working on Ios and Swift 3 and I want to parse HTML Code. 
Until now [Hpple](https://github.com/topfunky/hpple) did the trick for me using this code:

```
func parse_Html_Text(url:String)
{
    let data = NSData(contentsOf: URL(string: url)!)
    let doc = TFHpple(htmlData: data! as Data!)
}
```

But when I'm trying to get html code from a query url (like this one: [link](http://www.buchen.travel/im-web-expose-booking/index.php?interface=17627&obj=44830&l=1)), then my app crashes and I get *Thread1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION* error in this line:

```
let doc = TFHpple(htmlData: data! as Data!)
```

I also tried Alamofire's request method but I didnt manage to make it work

I'm stucked two days with this so any help will be appreciated.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that you use Swift 3. Probably the library expects an NSData object but I would suggest to write your function like the following:

```
func parse_Html_Text(url: String) {
    if let safeUrl = URL(string: url) {
        let data = try? Data(contentsOf: safeUrl)
        let doc = TFHpple(htmlData: data as? NSData)
    }
}
```

In this case keep in mind that we are not handling possible error from the data setter.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply! The code give me error: Cannot convert value of type "NSData?" to expected argument type 'Data!'

in line: 
    let doc = TFHpple(htmlData: data as? NSData)

Xcode suggest to add : as Data! at the end but , even thought it builds in that way, it returns empty doc and its unable to be parsed